# Angular image adding random string to src but not updating

Tags: angular, image, src

I have an image in my template. When you click on the image, it allows you to upload a new one. But it doesn't refresh the image. I tried adding random characters, and I can see that there are different characters at the beginning of the function cycle, and at the end, but the image is still not updating unless you refresh the page.
this is my template

```html
<img id="logoImg" [src]="agency.logoUrl" (click)="selectImage.click()" />
  <input id="inputLogoImg" type="file" accept=".png,.jpg"  #selectImage (change)="uploadLogo($event)" >
```

this is my component

```js
  uploadLogo(event): void {
    const logoImg = document.getElementById('logoImg') as HTMLImageElement;
    logoImg.src = logoImg.src + '#' + Math.random();
    // this.logoUrl = logoImg.src;
    // console.log(this.logoUrl)
    console.log(logoImg.src);
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const fileName = file.name;
    const fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    this.filePath = `${this.agencyId}.` + fileExt;
    this.afStorage.upload(this.filePath, file);
    logoImg.src = logoImg.src + '#' + Math.random();
    console.log(logoImg.src);
    // this.logoUrl = logoImg.src;
    // console.log(this.logoUrl)
    console.log(this.agencyId);
```

when I click on the image, I see two different paths, because different random number, but the image stays the same unless I reload.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace
`'#' + Math.random();`
with
`'?h=' + Math.random();`.

Answer (score 0):

User assigning same value to image src. You should use new src path in `agncy.logoUrl`

```js
  uploadLogo(event): void {
      const logoImg = document.getElementById('logoImg') as HTMLImageElement;
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      const fileName = file.name;
      const fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
      this.filePath = `${this.agencyId}.` + fileExt;
      // logoImg.src = logoImg.src + '#' + Math.random(); old code
      logoImg.src = this.afStorage.upload(this.filePath, file); 
      // this.afStorage.upload return new file uploaded path to src 
      console.log(logoImg.src);
      console.log(this.agencyId);
  }
```

Comment: re answer from rajratna maitry, I'm getting an erro4: TS2322: Type 'AngularFireUploadTask' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: re answer from @Kenarius, it's not reloading the image, but giving this error:  GET https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/agency-logos-paid-keeper/o/thumbnails%2FpCllf5k3rBFdNFoecV9Y_700x100.png?alt=media&token=601a2517-3afa-4e91-a91b-ce681b2a1560?h=0.0944119909100023?h=0.2265510507369639 403. I tried the same thing but with a # and a & sign. The url shows me the change and there's no error, but the image still won't reload.